# Why am I not getting access to the full internal storage space?

Tags: root-access, internal-storage, data-recovery

***Please note:** There are similar questions to this one, but this is different: in this case I am root reading all the block data **directly** from `/dev/block/*`, not a regular user trying to save files to pre-partitioned areas.*

According to the internal memory capabilities this phone, a HTC One V (a version tailored for Cricket Wireless if it makes a difference), there should be [*"4 GB (1 GB user available)"*](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_v-4575.php).

However, when I create a `dd` image of the internal storage (accessible through `/dev/block/mmcblk0`), it tells me the resulting image is 2.3GB large. Even if I create an image of each partition individually, [the result is still 2.3GB](https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/cbe8da2642ed6dc5526f).

Why is there a discrepancy between how much storage is listed on the phone's specs, and how much data can be accessed through `/dev/block/*`?

Comment: Apparently, some of the flash isn't mapped through that mechanism.  You can look into the kernel configuration, but it is also possible that the radio firmware ("baseband") which runs outside the kernel (and often on a different processor core) "owns" that, and the Linux kernel has either not been notified of its existence, or actually locked out.